# flex TileLayout - want equal tile width but not height

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I am working on a Flex mobile project and am using a TileLayout to layout a bunch of groups. The problem is, if any text in one of the groups spans several lines, ALL tiles get resized to the same height. I need the tile width to be the same for all tiles, but I want the tile height to be the tallest only on each row. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around for this. I had to write a custom layout that calculates the number of columns and the max height for each row.